# Is it grammatically right to start a sentence using the phrase 'As there are/is'

Tags: grammar, phrases

Scenario:

There will not be any class today, since some other programs are arranged during the duration of class.

Is it good to write this sentence as:

> As there are some programs going on, there will be no class today.

Comment: Why do you think it might not be? What rule do you believe is being violated here?

Comment: "As there are some programs going on, there will be no class today." is a bit vague, and it might be nice to provide slightly more information to justify the closure (what programs? when? for whom?). But I don't see a grammatical issue.

Comment: Yes, it's syntactically fine. The preposition "as" has a meaning similar to "because" or "since". It is functioning as head of a PP with the content clause "there are some programs going on" as its complement. The PP is functioning as an adjunct of reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all true that you can't use a coordinating conjunction at the start of a sentence. (This is coming from a high school chick) (But it might not be somebody's policy or style to do so, but it's not un-grammatical. There is no rule that is being broken.) It's just what schools teach (for some odd reason) but there's nothing wrong with starting a sentence with "As". "As" isn't actually a coordinating conjunction, it's a subordinating conjunction. As far as I know, no one has ever claimed that you can't (as a preference or rule) start a sentence with a subordinating conjunction. (There is only a problem if the sentence that starts with a subordinating conjunction has a single clause.)

Comment: "As" is not a subordinator (your subordinating conjunction), but a preposition with a meaning similar to "because" or "since". "As" is thus head of a PP with the content clause "there are some programs going on" as its complement. The PP is functioning as an adjunct of reason.

Comment: I appreciate your comment! Schools just don't teach the right things anymore, so I'm actually learning more from here than I am from school. So, thanks!